# Coming up with a wrapper for atomically accessing shared memory

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, locking

I am struggling with multithreading concepts here.

There are two threads that access a shared struct. Idea is to have `ThreadTwo` acquire the lock first and sets `data` to true, and then `ThreadOne` run...which goes to sleep if `data` is set to `true`, and wake up once signalled after `data` being set to `false`.

What I'm seeing happen: `ThreadOne` goes to sleep, and after `ThreadTwo` disables `data`, both the threads seem to be in a deadlock state or rather they're stuck.

My understanding is: I unlock the mutex at the end of `AccessShm(shmInfo, GET)`, and I believe `pthread_cond_signal` requires to have lock already acquired because it unlocks before going to sleep, and once signalled from `ThreadTwo`, `ThreadOne` wakes up, acquires a lock, and attempts to acquire again inside `AccessShm` but can't because it's already been acquired hence the hang?

```
typedef enum
{
    SET,
    GET
} Task;

typedef struct
{
    volatile bool data;     
    pthread_mutex_t pMutex;
    pthread_cond_t cv;
} ShmInfo;

bool AccessShm(ShmInfo *pShm, Task t, ...)  
{
    va_list args;
    bool setValue = true;
    bool retValue = true;

    va_start(args, t);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&pShm->pMutex);

    switch (t)
    {
        case SET:
            setValue = va_arg(args, bool);  
            pShm->data = setValue;
        
            if (setValue == false)
            {
                pthread_cond_signal(&pShm->cv); // wake up only when pShm->data is disabled
            }
            break;
        
        case GET:
            retValue = pShm->data;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pShm->pMutex);
    return retValue;
}

void ThreadOne(void *arg)
{
    ShmInfo *shmInfo = (ShmInfo *) arg;
    while(1)
    {
        while(AccessShm(shmInfo, GET) == true) 
        {
          pthread_cond_wait(&shmInfo->cv, &shmInfo->pMutex); 
        }
        // ...
    }
}

void ThreadTwo(void *arg)
{
    ShmInfo *shmInfo = (ShmInfo *) arg;
    // ...
    AccessShm(shmInfo, SET, true);
    
    // some work/delay
    AccessShm(shmInfo, SET, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you're not calling `va_end()` (which is required) in `AccessShm()`?

Apparently not.

The structure of your use of the mutex and condition variable is a little unusual. Typically, the mutex is locked when `pthread_cond_wait()` is called in order to ensure determinism.

I suggest moving the locking/unlocking of the mutex out of `AccessShm()` and into both `ThreadOne()` and `ThreadTwo()`. The call to `pthread_cond_signal()` can be left in `AccessShm()` on the assumption that the mutex is locked, which you can verify via a call to `assert(pthread_mutex_trylock(&pShm->pMutex))` at the beginning of that function's body.

Comment: yeah that was something I was missing but certainly not the answer. Don't you think it comes down to the locking flows that's causing it? I'm not fully certain but trying to fully understand...

Comment: the idea of this wrapper is to access the variable atomically and without having to manually invoke mutex lock and unlock in the application to avoid any havoc in case of a missed lock/unlock. `pthread_cond_signal` must be called after having acquired a lock anyways so wouldn't it be better to leave the locking mechanism inside the wrapper, no?

Comment: @xyf That's good thinking except that the mutex should be locked when `pthread_cond_wait()` is called, and that's done outside the wrapper -- so you might as well accept what's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are not locking the mutex associated with your condition variable before calling `pthread_cond_wait()`.

You ***must*** only call `pthread_cond_wait()` with the associated mutex locked.

Per [the POSIX `pthread_cond_wait()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html)(bolding mine):

> The `pthread_cond_timedwait()` and `pthread_cond_wait()` functions shall block on a condition variable. **The application shall ensure that these functions are called with `mutex` locked by the calling thread**; otherwise, an error (for PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK and robust mutexes) or **undefined behavior** (for other mutexes) results.
>
> ...

Comment: Sorry, how's the mutex lock not associated with my conditional variable? There's only CV and one MUTEX in the application

Comment: @xyf Your code for `ThreadOne` calls `AccessShm` which locks and then *unlocks* the mutex. You then call `pthread_cond_wait` without holding the mutex. That is illegal for two reasons: 1) The standards say so. 2) What happens if the call to `pthread_cond_signal` occurs after you call `pthread_mutex_unlock` but before you call `pthread_cond_wait`? You will wait for something that has already happened, possibly forever.

Comment: I see your point, but `pthread_cond_signal` is always called after the lock has been acquired inside `AccessShm` though

Comment: @xyf Your code isn't working, the standard says, "You must do X", and you're arguing about why you don't really need to do X?!?

Comment: It’s not about arguing but trying to understand the working of things under the hood :) do you think it’s possible to have a wrapper that does what I’m doing or quite not?